# Is there a special way to bundle reactjs production app?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, react-router

I developed a react application with laravel and ran **npm run prod**, the code was built and I deployed online. But for some reason it works perfectly on my laptop and desktop, but requests doesn't work on my mobile phone.

That is, I get to see the landing page on my mobile phone when I visit the URL, but requests doesn't work.

Comment: is your request reaching your api at all?

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't get any error as I am using my mobile phone's browser.

Comment: I just bundled and deployed. You can try it out on http://18.188.12.71. Thanks